# NAudio - bitrate vs sampling rate

Tags: naudio

for raw PCM data with sampling rate - say Fs - what bit rate or sample rate to use? Can I set WaveFormat sample rate parameter to same as Fs?

Comment: I have raw PCM file sampled at 10 kHz. How should I do if sound card does not have exact sample rate for it by using  NAudio? code example?

Answer (score 1):

NAudio will calculate the bit rate for you, if you provide sample rate and channels in the WaveFormat constructor with two parameters. (you can also specify bit depth, but this will normally be 16).

You can specify any sample rate you like, but if you want to play it easily in Windows, go for a standard value (e.g. 44100, 32000, 48000, 16000).

Answer (score 0):

96 khz and 44.1 kHz are standard audio sampling rates, bit rate will span from 4 to 32 depending on your needs

Comment: you may also be able to convert the file to a different rate and output in a different format with [audacity](http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/playing-raw-pcm-audio-using-audacity/)